# Verificar se e-mail possui brecha através do site have I been Pwned (Selenium/Python)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, testes-automatizados

Boa tarde!
Estou utilizando o Selenium para teste automatizado. O objetivo é verificar, através de uma lista de e-mails institucionais, se o e-mail está em alguma brecha e enviar um e-mail padrão solicitando atualização da senha;

O problema surgiu quando busquei por um e-mail com brecha e o corpo do site é exatamente igual para um e-mail que não está em nenhuma brecha;

Tentei class name, id, page source e nada parece funcionar nesse caso.

Como podem ver no trecho abaixo.. O primeiro e-mail está num site vazado e o segundo e-mail não caiu em nenhum vazamento de dados, mas ambos caem na primeira condição.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Não seria melhor usar a [API](https://haveibeenpwned.com/API/v3) que eles fornecem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está verificando se o conteúdo `Oh no - pwned` está no código fonte da página, não se está na tela.

Se você olhar o código fonte da página (como sempre é bom fazer se está desenvolvendo com selenium), vai que essa string sempre está lá  - está lá assim como  a contraparte `Good news — no pwnage found!`.

Em outras palavras: o texto para as duas respostas - se o email vazou ou não vazou, está presente na página - é o Javascript da página que faz um, ou o outro, ser visível.

Mais ainda, a página *tem* uma API, e uma API normalmente é algo mais propíciod e se usar do que uma consulta por selenium - por vários motivos, mas o principal dele é que uma API sempre vai ser bem documentada e vai te trazer respostas trafegando bem menos dados e usando menos recursos do lado do servidor - e do lado do cliente, você tem a garantia que a resposta não vai mudar por conta de uma reformulação estética da página.

Os úncos casos em que você iria preferir usar o Selenium pra fazer uma consulta, se há uma API são: (1) a app já faz várias outras coisas com selenium, e essa consulta seria só uma coisa a mais e simples de de fazer, sem precisar multiplicar a lógica da aplicação para incluir a consulta a API, além do Selenium já usado para outras páginas; (2) o acesso da API é restrito por login e/ou conta paga, e você quer usar o Selenium para tentar uma consulta gratuita.

Bom - no caso dessa questão, parece que você cai exatamente nos dois casos acima  - tanto já tem parte da app usando selenium pronta, como o uso da API requer uma assinatura.

O problema é que - se a API requer uma assinatura, isso quer dizer que por vários motivos os autores do site não querem ou não podem fornecer a informação a uma aplicação automatizada de forma gratuita  - então insistir em usar o Selenium para fazer a consulta contornando a api é se apropriar indevidamente do serviço do portal.

Aqui está a página do haveibeenpwned explicand por que ele teve que fechar o serviço e passar a cobrar pelo uso da API (é barato, de repente você pode comprar uma chave de API para seu projeto: https://www.troyhunt.com/authentication-and-the-have-i-been-pwned-api/

Se quiser insistir em tentar usar o serviço sem ter um token de API, e com o selenium, claro que ninguém vai quebrar por conta disso, e muita das coisas que fazemos no dia a dia, mesmo em trabalho corporativo, as vezes tem alguns contornos desses=- mas tecnicamente vai ser desafiador: você vai ter que usar algo que identifica qual das duas mensagens está *visível* na página, não apenas presente no codigo fonte da página nesse caso.

Vejo três maneiras de fazer isso, e por questão de tempo e recursos não tenho como te dar uma resposta inteira: Verificar no CSS ativo da página (com as ferramentas de desenvolvedor), que propriedades estão ativas/inativas para aparecer uma ou outra resposta na tela, e verificar *essas* propriedades pelo Selenium - talvez seja a visibilidade das `div`  `<div id="pwnedWebsitesContainer">` e a div com id `noPwnage` - mas você vai ter que checar isso você mesma.

Se pela checagem das propriedades de CSS para os elementos visíveis você não conseguir localizar, vai ter que usar alguma API do Selenium para ver se um elemento está visível na página, e não simplesmente "presente" - parece que a chamada ".isDisplayed" do Selenium, nas classes acima, pode ser o suficiente - de qualquer forma, você vai ter que olhar a documentação - https://developers.perfectomobile.com/display/TT/isDisplayed%28%29+and+NoSuchElementError+exception

---

Por fim, mas não menos importante: bem-vinda ao stackoverflow em português.
Por favor, ao fazer perguntas, **não** use *imagens* para colar seu código, mensagens de erros ou representações de dados.  Sempre cole o seu código, as mensagens de erro impressas, e os seus dados **como texto** (formate o código usando os botões da interface ou a marcação markdown) -- Imagens não permite uma busca, não permitem indexação de trechos do seu código pelos bancos do stackoverflow, não permitem que pessoas respondendo sua pergunta copiem e colem trechos do seu código para dar exemplos - -nesse caso mesmo, eu tive que ficar indo e voltando para reproduzier a mensagem que você espera na tela "Yo've been pwned", quando teria sido muito mais confortável pra mim copiar e colar esse trechinho